# Xcode 4.5 - can't install developer .ipa files via iTunes

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I had many times making a developer builds for testing purpose and everything was working fine. Was! After updating my Xcode to version 4.5 I can't install my developer builds via iTunes.
This situation is the same on every device I had in provision profile.

What I have and what I had checked double times with other developers to avoid personal mistake:
1) developer certificate
2) developer provision profile with added right devices
3) right build process

After success build of app me and other developers try to install it via iTunnes (10.7) but only error dialog appears that Synchronisation failed.

**The very important info is, that I can build runnable app in xCode 4.2 and install it via iTunnes without any troubles with the same certificate and provision profiles**

**I can run the app directly on device if I run it via Xcode**

Checked all apple's recommendation and I have all right: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2009/tn2242.html

Checked lots of forums with similar issue and I have done many steps trying to reduce this problem starting with revoking ALL certificates, making new developers profiles with particular devices, cleaned tmp folders in Xcode together with build dir. I had delete all certificates, keys from KeyChain and import new ones. Deleted all provision profiles on device and install new one. Clean project, change a build architecture "armv", base SDK - Latest iOS 6.

**Many thanks for your responce!!!**

This is a part of log file from device (iPhone5 iOS 6.1)

```
Nov  7 23:31:04  lockdownd[29] <Notice>: 016ca000 __copy_itunes_value_block_invoke_0: com.apple.mobile.iTunes.store/PurchaseTypes -> (null)

Nov  7 23:31:09  installd[31] <Error>: 0x343000 handle_install: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/denik4.ipa" requested by itunesstored

Nov  7 23:31:09  installd[31] <Error>: 0x343000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app cz.newslab.denik
>
Nov  7 23:31:09  installd[31] <Error>: profile not valid: 0xe8008012
>
Nov  7 23:31:09  installd[31] <Error>: 0x343000 install_embedded_profile: Could not install embedded profile: 0xe8008012
>
Nov  7 23:31:09  installd[31] <Error>: Nov  7 23:31:09  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
>
Nov  7 23:31:09  mobile_assertion_agent[94] <Notice>: service_one_connection: Connection closed for client iTunes.
>
Nov  7 23:31:10  installd[31] <Error>: entitlement 'keychain-access-groups' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
>
Nov  7 23:31:10  installd[31] <Error>: entitlement 'aps-environment' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
>
Nov  7 23:31:10  installd[31] <Error>: entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
>
Nov  7 23:31:10  installd[31] <Error>: 0x343000 verify_signer_identity: MISValidateSignatureAndCopyInfo failed for /var/tmp/install_staging.yDZPNm/foo_extracted/Payload/denik.app/denik: 0xe8008016
>
Nov  7 23:31:10  installd[31] <Error>: 0x343000 do_preflight_verification: Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.yDZPNm/foo_extracted/Payload/denik.app
>
Nov  7 23:31:10  installd[31] <Error>: 0x343000 install_application: Could not preflight application install
>
Nov  7 23:31:10  itunesstored[66] <Error>: 0x1786000 MobileInstallationInstall: failed with -1
>
Nov  7 23:31:10  installd[31] <Error>: 0x343000 handle_install: API failed
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The important line is this one:

installd[31] : profile not valid: 0xe8008012

I've seen this error myself with one of our IPAs recently. It was solved by re-issuing the profile from the iOS Provisioning portal (simply make a simple change, undo it, then submit - that should regenerate the profile), updated the Xcode code signing identity to use the new profile, rebooted the device, and then tried again. It then seemed to install fine.

We weren't able to close in on a root cause of the issue, but once we'd gone through those steps we haven't seen it again.

Comment: Worked for me, could be due to apple changes to the certificate/profiles management, make sure you check the expiration, and encryption keys.