# iOS application deletes itself once downloaded

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, provisioning

I'm developing an application for a company for iOS > 5.0 using Xcode 4.6.1. To test application, i archived application using `Save for Enterprise or Ad-hoc deployment`. I've checked also `Save for Enterprise Distribution` and filled appropriate fields. So far, i'm able to create an `myApp.ipa` file and `myApp.plist` file. I've created an url to `myApp.plist`. Once, i clicked url, myApp starts to download correctly. My problem is that once download's finished, myApp deletes itself and i got no crash log,simply nothing. I googled it and got nothing either. The problem is that one of my client is able to download myApp and to use it. I thought the problem is related to provisioning profile,but both devices is registered the same provisioning profile. So, i'm clueless. What could be the problem ? How is it possible that myApp deletes itself ?

Thank you all.

**EDIT :** here is the console log.

> May 10 12:02:15 IK installd[3728] : profile not valid:
>   0xe8008012
>
> May 10 12:02:15 IK installd[3728] : 00403000
>   install_embedded_profile: Could not install embedded profile:
>   -402620398
>
> May 10 12:02:15 IK installd[3728] : entitlement
>   'keychain-access-groups' has value not permitted by a provisioning
>   profile
>
> May 10 12:02:15 IK installd[3728] : entitlement
>   'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning
>   profile
>
> May 10 12:02:15 IK SpringBoard[15] : Killing
>   net.caretta.iAnahtar for termination assertion

Comment: @Downvoter, please add a comment why you downvote to improve my question.

Comment: How is your client installing the app?

Comment: @JavierBeltrán From my company server , does it matter ?

Comment: Which OS Version is your device running?

Comment: @Mohith my device is running under iOS 5.1,my deployment targer is > iOS 5.0

Comment: There should be some meaningful error messages in the device log, they always are.

Comment: @Sulthan,added console log, but nothing in device log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems very similar to:

[Xcode 4.5 - can't install developer .ipa files via iTunes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294510/xcode-4-5-cant-install-developer-ipa-files-via-itunes/13741236#13741236)

The main symptom I observed in the case I had like that problem was that the IPA would try to install, then eventually it would get downloaded - then straight away it would disappear.

If the following line:

> installd[31] : profile not valid: 0xe8008012

appears in the console log, then you may want to try re-issuing the profile from the iOS Provisioning portal (simply make a simple change, undo it, then submit - that should regenerate the profile), update the Xcode code signing identity to use the new profile, reboot the device, and then try again. Not guaranteed to fix the problem, but it might be worth trying.

Comment: Thank you.It was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Is this an enterprise app (is the developer account issuing the certificate an Enterprise account)? If not, you will need to ensure both the device UDIDs are in the mobileprovision.

The app is not really deleted, it is downloaded but when the OS tries to install it, it fails and that's why the icon is removed.

A few things to check

1. Are you creating the ipa in the correct manner? Make sure you use the correct certificates and mobile provisions and are using the correct option when exporting the ipa
2. Both the device UDIDs must be included in the provisioning profile
3. The device must have ability to install the app (are Restrictions turned on to disable installation of apps?)

Try using a service like Testflight.

Comment: I've double checked that both device UDIDs are int the mobile provision and included in the provisioning profile. Let's say that i didn't create the ipa in the correct manner, how would i be able to download and install that ipa in another device. The device in which i can install the app is exactly same as another. So, i think it's not the issue here. Both `Restrictions` are disabled.

Comment: In that case the only thing which could be going wrong is the mobileprovision. Did you check if the mobileprovision is installed on the device (under Settings->General->Profiles)?

Answer (score 0):

If your deployment target is a later version than the device OS this happens. I dont see any other reason for it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a Newsstand app is it? Because when you install a Newsstand app, you'll initially see what looks like a regular app icon while it is downloading, but once the download has finished the icon will disappear and it will automatically move to the Newsstand bookshelf.

Comment: No,it's not a Newsstand app.

Comment: You say there is nothing in the crash log, but what about the console log? You can use something like the [System Console app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/system-console/id431158981?mt=8) to view the console logs from the device itself if that helps.