# Xamarin Forms: IOS app not installing on ipad mini

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I am developing an app using Xamarin Forms PCL project. For my IOS project in info.plist file I have set "8.0" as the minimum ios version. I created an ad-hoc ipa file then I installed the app on my ipad device which is running on ios 9.1 but when i tried running my app on ipad mini which is running on ios 10.1, app is getting removed from the device as soon as its installation finishes. Is there any compatibility issue?

Info.plist-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
        <integer>2</integer>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>8.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>XYZ</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.yourcompany.FISE</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile~ipad</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
  <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
  <dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Can you please attach your device with Apple configurator & see what are you getting in Log. Download Apple Configurator from https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12

It will help to trace the error.

Comment: Look into these answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606833/in-house-app-disappears-after-install

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304880/ios-application-deletes-itself-once-downloaded

please re-check all the configuration settings in your .plist like bundleID etc

Comment: This is likely because you haven't created your provisioning profile correctly on apples development certificate site. You need to ensure that the provisioning profile contains the UID for your iPad otherwise it will install, then instantly remove it when it detects that it doesn't match.

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt if that so, then why it is working in my ipad and not in my ipad mini?

Comment: because they both have different UID's ? so are you sure that both devices were selected when you created your provisioning profile...

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt yes

Comment: Well the only reason I have ever seen it install and remove itself is when there's an issue with the certificates, I would suggest remaking them all and trying again.