# App not installing on iPhone 5s

Tags: iphone, xcode, model-view-controller

I have a MVC web app, which is distributed through ad hoc for iPhone using Xcode 4.5. The Xcode iPhone simulator is 6.1. The app installs fine on previous versions of iPhones, but not installing on iPhone 5s.

Can someone tell me, how I can make adhoc distribution for latest iPhone. Should I update Xcode or any other workaround?

Comment: Did you add your iPhone 5s with your Provisioning Profile?

Comment: Yes, the UDID is included in the profile.

Comment: Ok great, than I think you have to update to xCode 5.0. It fixed a lot of problems with my iPhone 5s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there is not need to use the iOS 7 SDK, all iOS 7 devices are capable of running iOS 6 apps.

Just make sure that you have the correct UDID, if the UDID start with `FFFFF` the UDID is not corrcet. Since iOS 7 the developers can not access the UDID any more. Thus all the UDID app are not longer working.

You should use iTunes to retrieve the UDID of the device.

Comment: Why the downvote, please explain what is wrong with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well Yes, Updation is required. This is because iPhone 5S has iOS 7.0. You will need to update your xcode 4.5 to xcode 5 which is required for running ios 7.0 . Xcode 4.5 **will not** create builds for ios 7.0 . Therefore you need to install a version of xcode that supports iOS 7.0 and later.

Comment: an iPhone running iOS 7 can run App build for iOS 6 with out any problems. I've been able to install iOS 6 build via TestFlight on iOS 7 devices.

Comment: Yes I know but u need to build the code on xcode 5 to make it run for ios 7 or lesser ... He is using xcode 4.5 .... this wud make the app run for ios 6 and lower NOT 7.0

Comment: Not true, If you build with iOS 6 SDK and Xocde 4.5 (or 4.6) your app can be installed on iOS 7. There is no need to build with the iOS 7 SDK unless you want you want to support iOS 7. If you are targeting iOS 6 you can still use iOS 6 SDK and it will run on a iOS 7 device.

Comment: But he wants the app to run on iPhone 5 which has iOS 7 by default rite ? so he would be targeting iOS 7 also .... Am I rite ? He would have to make a link.....

Comment: @rckoenes sir, What can I do to make it install on iPhone 5s?

Comment: Yes he want to run an Ad-Hoc build on the iPhone 5S, which is running iOS 7. But that does not mean that you have to build you app using the iOS 7 SDK. iOS 7 is capable of running iOS 6 build of apps. Otherwise you would not be able to run any older app from the app store.

Comment: @Zorro I just added the UDID to my profile and everything just worked. Make sure you get the UDID from that device using iTunes, all the UDID app in the appstore are no longer working with iOS7 and will give an incorrect UDID.

Comment: Ummm I mentioned that in the answer ... Though I did not suggest the link part ....

Comment: The strange thing is that, iPhone 4s with iOS 7 installs and runs the app, but on iPhone 5s with iOS 7, it stucks and does not installs.

Comment: @Zorro make sure that you have the correct UDID if the UDID start with `FFFFFF` it is not correct. Also clean your build before building the new Ad-Hoc build.

Comment: Yes! the UDID starts with FFFFFF. I do clean the build. what to do with the UDID?

Comment: @Zorro you us iTunes to get the UDID, **DO NOT USE AN APP**

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue, and I found my answer here: [Xcode 4.5 - can't install developer .ipa files via iTunes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294510/xcode-4-5-cant-install-developer-ipa-files-via-itunes/13741236#13741236)

Using the accepted answer there, my issues for installing on the new 5S went away. I just had to rebuild the distribution profile, make a new .ipa file with it and try again. Strange error, but the answer worked for me.