# iOS7 distributed App installation via iTunes fails without error

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, itunes

After I my App as usually I tried to install it via iTunes.
It has successfully synced to the iPhone, but the Icon is grayed out and it seems like the installation has not finished

Where you normally find the App-Name "Installation ..." has appeared.

Can't find any log or error message

(can't push the App with the development machine because of Apple's new security feature => "do you trust this computer" which just won't disappear)

Comment: Are you trying to install an ad-hoc version of the app via a .ipa file?

Comment: Are you using an authentic data cable?

Comment: Make sure that the provisioning profile is in the device.

Comment: Yeah i try to install id via Ad-Hoc signed with the development provisioning profile, worked for me before
profiles are installed and valid to 2014

Answer (score 3):

There is actually one log you can look at during the install; go to  the Organizer window in Xcode, look at your device in the Devices tab, and look at the Device Logs. There should be several issues that will be logged during the iTunes install: rollback notifications, errors and such.

Look for one error in particular, similar to this one:

`installd[31] : profile not valid: 0xe8008012`

As Nikos M. alluded to in his comment above, this would indicate a provisioning profile issue. When I had this issue, my provisioning profile was up to date, but the app still wasn't installing. I found this question on this site, and the accepted answer fixed the issue for me: [Xcode 4.5 - can't install developer .ipa files via iTunes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294510/xcode-4-5-cant-install-developer-ipa-files-via-itunes/13741236#13741236)

Basically, it's a problem with the provisioning profile. Not sure why it happens, but it prevents the app from being installed on *some* devices *sometimes*. As answered in the question above, you need to get on the iOS Developer Portal, make a small edit to your provisioning profile (your **Ad-Hoc Distribution Profile**, not the Development profile), change it back, regenerate the profile and download it again. Rebuild your .ipa file with this fresh profile, replace your old .ipa with this new one in iTunes and try installing the app again.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem with a coworker, and after some consternation, we realized he was using a device that we had not authorized during the certificate generation.  The result was as you described (a gray overlay on the application's icon that could not be opened).