# app showing Installing for long time

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

For one of company we have created iPhone app as in-house. This app is not on app store. We provide them updated provision file everytime.

When client tries to installing app on one of iPhone, it keep on saying Installing... But installation never occurs.

Any idea why this is happening?

I have iOS 7 on client iPhone.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS7 distributed App installation via iTunes fails without error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19980169/ios7-distributed-app-installation-via-itunes-fails-without-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be for many reasons but the most common are:

1. Did not sign with the right provisioning profile.
2. The users device is not set up in an ad hoc distribution profile.
3. Is it signed using a proper enterprise provisioning profile?
4. The information in the plist if downloading from a site does not match the file being downloaded.
5. Poor internet connection.

I would go down the list and doubly check everything. Make sure that if you're building an adhoc profile from an app store account that it is actually being refreshed and not duplicated in Xcode when building with the provisioning profile that contains the proper UDID for the device they want to install it on.